# iOS build and Mac build for intel macs vs M1 macs

Tags: ios, macos, intel, apple-m1

We have set the iOS app to work in M1 chip Macs, we see the same app in the mac app store - so the same bundle id.

However, to make the same app work on intel chip Macs, we are creating a native Mac App. Should we use the same bundle id as iOS?

For push notifications for Macs, will the same APNS setting we use for iOS work for Mac too?

Comment: You cannot use the same bundle id.  IMO you should either make a Mac app (which will work on Intel and Apple Silicon Macs) *and* create an iOS app which is not available on macOS *or* create an iOS app which is also available on Apple Silicon and do not support Intel Macs *or* create an iOS app and make this available to macOS using Catalyst.  If you are going to create a Mac native app for Intel, why wouldn't you just use this for Apple Silicon too?

Comment: Our iOS app works seamlessly on M1 Chip / Apple Silicon Macs without any issues. It is available in Mac App Store - no additional code

We need to create Mac App for Intel Macs

Comment: My point is you can't make a Mac app for *intel macs*. If you make a Mac app it is available for *all macs*. The ability to run an iOS app on Apple Silicon macs provides an opportunity for developers to make their app available on Mac with little or no additional effort. Since you are making a Mac native app it doesn't make sense for people to run the iOS version on their macs, regardless of the processor.

Comment: Got it. Here is my predicament. I have an App on iOS and it is available in M1 Mac App Store and it is not in Intel Mac App Store. It is in Xamarin. We use some custom controls that are not part of a typical Mac set of controls and they work like charm without issues in the existing M1 Mac App store. However, because the app is not in the intel Mac App Store, we need to build a new app for Mac and it will be with reduced functionality as few controls won't work out the of the box.

Comment: Ok, well you can either release a new Mac app that will be available for Intel Macs and visible to M1 Macs beside your iOS app in the Mac app store or you could remove your iOS app from the Mac App Store and release a catalyst build of your iOS app in the Mac app store